# Wordlist generate: uppercase and each character appears only one

Tags: password-cracking, wordlist

I want to generate a wordlist that contains only uppercase characters on length 8 and each character appears only once.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you done any research on existing tools that exist? Have you considered writing your own simple program to do this?

Comment: I suggest to move the question to SO.

Comment: This is not a security question. This is a programming/scripting question. This also looks like homework.

Answer (score 1):

The python `itertools` module is handy for these types of problems.  Here is a short python script that creates the list that you are looking for:

```
import itertools

maxlength=4
charlist=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

permutations=list(itertools.permutations(charlist, maxlength))
for p in permutations:
    print(''.join(p))
```

Setting `maxlength`=4 in the above script, to produce passwords 4 characters in length, this produces:

```
ABCD
ABCE
ABCF
ABCG
ABCH
ABCI
ABCJ
ABCK
ABCL
ABCM
ABCN
ABCO
ABCP
ABCQ
ABCR
ABCS
ABCT
ABCU
ABCV
ABCW
ABCX
ABCY
ABCZ
ABDC
ABDE
ABDF
ABDG
ABDH
ABDI
ABDJ
ABDK
ABDL
ABDM
ABDN
ABDO
ABDP
ABDQ
ABDR
ABDS
ABDT
ABDU
ABDV
ABDW
ABDX
ABDY
ABDZ
.
.
.
ZYXO
ZYXP
ZYXQ
ZYXR
ZYXS
ZYXT
ZYXU
ZYXV
ZYXW
```